# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Zero length BigInteger - with linked exception: [java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xjc

When I am validating integer field in WSDL with axis2 environment, I am getting the following error. This is working fine with xml beans. But I am getting error with xjc beans object. XSD validation failed!!!. I am getting this error, when I am passing empty value.

Please help me regarding this.

```
 <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="TypeName" type="types:PrincipalVariantType"/>
 <xsd:simpleType name="PrincipalVariantType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="2" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="3" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="4" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

**Stacktrace**

Comment: <xsd:simpleType name="typeName">
    
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
     <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
     <xsd:enumeration value="2" />
     <xsd:enumeration value="3" />
     <xsd:enumeration value="4" />
    </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>

Comment: [java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger] looks like case of incorrect input

Comment: i am getting this error,when i am passing empty. But my requirement is, it has throw error like only allowed values 1,2,3,4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### AS-IS

```
<xsd:simpleType name="PrincipalVariantType">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
       <xsd:enumeration value="1" />
       <xsd:enumeration value="2" />
       <xsd:enumeration value="3" />
       <xsd:enumeration value="4" />
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

In this case are valid only `<TypeName>1</TypeName>` or `<TypeName>2</TypeName>` or `<TypeName>3</TypeName>` or `<TypeName>4</TypeName>`

**NOTE**: Empty value is not a number, is not allowed for integer.

If you want an empty string change type in xsd:string and change restriction in

```
<xsd:simpleType name="PrincipalVariantType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:pattern value="[1-4\n]|()"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also working fine for me.

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:pattern value="(\s*[1-4\n]\s*)+"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```

Comment: Do you want all occurrences of [1-4] and spaces? e.g  `<TypeName>  3   3  </TypeName>` .. because your regexp allow this.